# Pointwise convergence preserves finite almost everywhere condition

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and let $f_n : E \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be a sequence of increasing measurable functions. Suppose $f(x) := \sup\{f_n(x) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. I've shown that $f$ is measurable, and $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$.

Now suppose that each $f_n$ is finite almost everywhere, that is, $\mu( f_n^{-1}( \{ \infty \} ))= 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. I want to prove that $f$ is also finite almost everywhere.
I think I have a proof attempt but not sure 100% that it's correct.

Since $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise, let $x \in E$ and let $\varepsilon = 1$. Then there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_{n_0}(x) - 1 < f(x) < f_{n_0}(x) + 1$. From this it follows that $f_{n_0}^{-1}( \{ \infty \} ) = f^{-1}( \{ \infty \} )$. Since $f_{n_0}$ is finite almost everywhere,  we get $\mu( f^{-1}( \{ \infty \} ) ) = 0  $ and we're done?

Thanks.

Comment: You proof assumes a priori that $f$ is finite. It may well be infinite everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample is $f_n(x)=n.$

There does not exist $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $\infty<n_0+1.$